# Developing professionally for iOS, Android and web - an insight

Tags: android, web, mobile, ios

This is not really a question on how to develop all three, I know various cross platform ways and so on. But I more want to know from developer standpoint how hard it is to basically develop iOS, Android and web apps?

I am currently in my first job as a mobile/web developer. I have already developed my first iPhone/iPad app and now I have to develop the app for android because the web version I tried just didn't perform as well as needed and web databases just did not seem to make the cut. But I am not sure it's possible to be good at developing all 3 in terms of remembering all the api's etc. I wouldn't say I have an issue with the programming languages just how to use the api's for the various platforms. Also, all the other languages I look at, in my spare time, just feel like I am spreading myself to thin.

Is it feasible for one person to be developing ios, android and web apps? Should I think about reducing it to iOS and web based apps?

I develop everything by myself, so I have no one to discuss what the best solutions are for everything and I am just trying to workout as I go along.

So any cross platform developers out there? Do companies have different teams for different platforms?

Any insight would just help me get my head together. Hopefully this question makes sense.

Comment: It depends on what type of app you are building. You have titanium that is famous for that.

Comment: Yeh i would think titanium would be such a good choice because then its just javascript and their api to develop with but I just know its not an option my boss would go with because of the cost. Plus I don't think they support blackberry as of yet.

Comment: Hi Scott. I'm an Android developer and just accepted a role to do mobile development in general, like yourself. That includes learning iOS to develop iPhone and iPad apps. I'm really looking forward to it and think it will improve my general programming skills (doing both). I know some developers who can do both and simply say, it's just another programming langauge / way to develop a mobile app. It's just a matter of doing and thereby gaining experience. I'm keeping an eye on the answers on your question! Regards, Johan.

Comment: Hi Johan, my main concerns are my ability to support 3 platforms on my own, with only the support of the internet. But i do enjoy developing for all 3 and since I completed my degree my experience and skill has improved more then I thought it would so that is a plus. I guess I just have to get into the thought as you said of their just another programming language / way to develop a mobile app and their not as different as I think they are. Im just hoping some people answer and make me feel like i'm not the only solo team out their and help me decide whats possible and not, thanks.

Comment: [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/) is also a valid alternative to titanium.

Answer (score 3):

I'm doing iOS, C# .NET desktop and Java Struts2 webapp development and I enjoy all of these. I think it's always a good idea to see how the different platforms approach their same goals and it gives you a greater overall understanding of the languages and frameworks involved. This means I'm not going forward with the same speed that my colleagues go that only do one of these platforms, but overall you're never limited because you can switch to something else anytime.

I also believe that you should start your projects on the most suitable platform and should then migrate it to other platforms as you see their success or begin something else if you don't see them working out.

Comment: Im going to keep on with the many different platforms im using I am slowly starting to be able to swap between them quite easily sometimes the api's get me tho. I do wish i could progress a little faster takes me a few days to get back into iOS development say after 3 months in web development. I want to be able to improve my switch over time and not be writing javascript instead of objective c. But its good to know there are developers that develop for a lot of platforms because thats the way i seem to be going.

Answer (score 3):

I have been working with Android an iOS, with web-based backends for over a year now, and it certainly is feasible. I've found that insight from the alternate platform has made the apps respectively better.

To your concern about not having anyone to bounce things off of, I go to my local GTUG (Google Tech User Group) and iPhone Developers Groups, and they're a great source of support when you're stuck on something, or need advice on the best way to proceed. Check meetup.com to see if there's a group near you.

Comment: Just need to find more time to improve android development.  Yeh i live in the uk so hopefully i can find a way to meet up with the groups but usually they are a bit too far away, but it would be really good to meet up with other developers who are working on the same platforms as i am.